# Redundant Router and Load Balancing vs. DDoS attack

Tags: ddos

With a small server farm at a hoster with great support and conditions, I worry about the increasing number of DDoS attacks against this hoster (not my web project, but other clients on the same location).

I have booked a redundant router and load balancer as managed service with this hoster to share the load with all the dedicated servers.

However, I was lost again today because another one's project was attacked with DDoS for hours :-(

Each hour means hundreds of dollars loss whenever my adserver and tracking is not reachable. Even time-out advertising have to be paid by me but can not be resold to my clients without the servers being available.
All the time, the servers, the load and traffic is OK and health, but no chance to keep this stable/online if the hoster is vulnerable.

Anyone has ideas or suggestions how to protect - even against DDoS?

Comment: If your web hosting provider cannot keep their network sufficiently operating under a DDoS to keep your servers available, even when you have dedicated servers, in my opinion, you should be looking for a new provider.

Comment: I agree with David W.  Your question doesn't explain why a DDoS against another client is taking your service down when you have dedicated servers.  As none of your servers should be seeing this DDoS traffic putting a redundant router and load balancer in front of your servers/services isn't going to solve any upstream problems with your datacenter/provider.

Comment: the router is not exclusive for me, so to say it is sharing performance and troubles, too... the servers are not touched...

Comment: Regardless of *why* the network is going down, if the provider can't keep their network up, you need to find a new provider or have the current one compensate you for the losses caused by their incompetence.  Preventing DDoS isn't easy, but preventing it from impacting other customers is.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple: balance the cost of downtime against the cost of protecting yourself from DDoS attacks.

This could mean paying your existing hosting provider for better isolation (and better SLAs), finding a better hosting provider or paying for one of the DDoS mitigation services.  Note that some of these have free offerings.

Whatever the numbers add up to, if the cost of downtime is greater than the cost of protecting yourself then you should pay for the upgrade.